# How do I "inject" structured configuration information with Spring?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, config

I have the following scenario:

There will be a Java language testbed system consisting of a number of "services" that collaborate by passing messages to one another. The service implementation is intended to be generic, i.e. there is no specific "business logic" contained within. For the purposes of the testbed it is important to be able to create various collections of services, configured externally (if possible).

The services themselves are unaware of the existence of any other service. Each service simply subscribes to the topics where it expects to receive information and publishes on topics where it sends information out to any waiting subscribers. With careful configuration it then would be possible to simulate a data flow graph.

The plan is to configure a given service instance by providing configuration information that describes the information needed to set up subscribers (readers) and publishers (writers). The configuration information may include other properties not related to publish/subscribe.

Below is a possible example:

**Note**: XML was chosen for the example simply because it's easy enough to read and allows for structured data.

```
<service>
    <name>Service A</name>
    <service-id>service ID</service-id>

    <publish>
        <per-second>5</per-second>
        <topic>
            <name>Topic 1</name>
            <class>org.xyz.Topic1</class>
            <!-- override 5/sec rate -->
            <per-second>10</per-second>
        </topic>
        <topic>
            <name>Topic 2</name>
            <class>org.xyz.Topic2</class>
        </topic>
    </publish>

    <subscribe>
        <topic>
            <name>Topic 3</name>
            <class>org.xyz.Topic3</class>
        </topic>
    </subscribe>
</service>

<service>
    <name>Service B</name>
    <service-id>service ID</service-id>

    <publish>
        <per-second>30</per-second>
        <topic>
            <name>Topic 3</name>
            <class>org.xyz.Topic3</class>
        </topic>
    </publish>

    <subscribe>
        <topic>
            <name>Topic 2</name>
            <class>org.xyz.Topic2</class>
        </topic>
    </subscribe>
</service>

...
```

I would like to use the Spring framework to help with the configuration of these services. **Note**: I am very new to Spring and am currently reading *Spring in Action* (and other sources) to educate myself.

What I would like to know is: How could I "inject" the configuration information to some sort of controller or factory that would then use it to create the collection of services and provide them with the necessary information to create the readers and writers they will use to receive and send messages?

From what I've read so far, Spring appears to be pretty powerful WRT to dependency injection and "bean wiring", but I don't know enough about what can (and cannot) be done, nor how to do it.

I'm not partial to whether Spring is configured by Java or XML. I just used XML because it easy to put together, allows for data structuring and seems to be used everywhere. If it makes more sense to specify the configuration a different way, just let me know.

How a given service would handle an event (i.e. receive a specific message) to possibly send out a message "response", or take some other action, is a topic outside the scope of this question. I am researching how that could be done - mainly at rules based processing. If anyone has suggestions, I will gladly take a look at them.

Answer (score 0):

Make a config file like this:

```
some.paremeter=cool
some.other.parameter=awesome
```

named `myconfig.properties`. Make sure the file is in your classpath, then include `-Dspring.config.name=myconfig` in your vm args; then in the xml you can use `${some.parameter}` etc. In particular, putting the config file in `<project-root>/config/` will work.

For example, here is a simple MongoClient from one of my projects that uses a spring config:

```
<!--Mongo-->
<bean id="mongoClient" class="com.mongodb.MongoClient">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="com.mongodb.MongoClientURI">
            <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String"
                             value="mongodb://${mongo.db.user}:${mongo.db.password}@${mongo.db.host}:${mongo.db.port}/${mongo.db.database}"/>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Comment: This uses a property file for the variable information. Is it possible to have structured information in properties files? I didn't think you could, which is why I used XML.

Comment: Depends on the property file. You can use yaml or json as well -- see the [Spring Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) docs. I'm saying that you can use plaintext properties files to hold static information, like strings of words that represent parameters. Once spring loads them, you can inject those params into the XML however you want.

Comment: Just curious: Is XML even an option for this?

Comment: I personally use spring XML configurations as opposed to annotation based configurations for most of my projects (even though annotations are the new-school.) Yes, one of the primary ways to configure a [spring application context](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring5/core/applicationcontext-xml-config-example/) is via XML.

Comment: Sorry, I must have worded my question incorrectly. You mentioned properties files in the forms of a "standard" Java properties file, or JSON or YAML for more structured config information. I'm wondering if XML is an option in this case? So, the Spring config could be XML or annotated Java classes, but could this config data be in a separate file (JSON, YAML, XML?) that is referenced by the Spring config?

Comment: I'm not sure if the config data can be stored in XML, but it definitely can be stored in YAML and JSON. See the Spring configuration link I attached in my first comment, under the section called "Loading YAML"